# MatLab global function issue

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm learning MatLab & hit a roadblock.

I have an `interface.fig` file with `interface.m` which is acting as my 'main' GUI window. From there another file; `bright.m` is called.

The file bright needs to update global variables in the main file as well as call functions, I have worked out the global variables out but cannot call functions.

Tried everything, looked at doing things like:

```
reDisplay();
evalin('base','reDisplay()');
interface.reDisplay();
interface>reDisplay();
```

But had no luck.

Comment: Can you describe specifically why you're unable to call functions from within bright.m? Why can't you simply call `output = myfunction(myArgs);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Only the first function in an M file is callable from outside of that file. If you want your functions to be globally accessible then you need to save them in independent files.

If you need state to be globally accessible between these functions pass them as arguments or consider using an Object Oriented approach to solving your problem.

Comment: AND the first function must be identical to the file name.

Comment: @dinkelk on R2012b, this isn't true.  the first function in the m file is what is executed when the function file is called.  Try creating a simple function but save the file with a different name. You'll get a warning saying "function 'XYZ' is known to MATLAB by its filename 'ABC'". Additionally you can call the XYZ function using name ABC

Comment: Interesting, I just tried it on R2012b for Linux, and I did not get the behavior you describe. I'll have to look into this more.

Answer (score 0):

If a function in Matlab is defined **inside** an m-file with file name different than function name - then there is no way of calling this function from outside its m-file.

In order for your `reDisplay` function to be visible to `bright.m`, you should have this function in its own m-file called `reDisplay.m`

Comment: Is this always the case? I seem to remember that if you have a single function that has a different name than the file it will still get called, although with the name of the m file and not the function name.

Comment: Well i have a window with the option boxes opening in smaller windows and when changed it needs to call this global function to set the changes..